# Parallax effect on tile map layers

Tags: cocos2d-x, parallax

i am using three layers of tiled map and i want to give parallax effect on these layers.
my code is:

```
     CCTMXTiledMap *city = CCTMXTiledMap::create("City.tmx");

     CCTMXLayer* ForegroundLayer = city->layerNamed("ForeGround");
 CCTMXLayer* BackgroundLayer1 = city->layerNamed("Background1");
 CCTMXLayer* BackgroundLayer2 = city->layerNamed("Background2");

     CCParallaxNode* voidNode = CCParallaxNode::create();

    // NOW add the 3 layers to the 'void' node

     voidNode->addChild(BackgroundLayer2, -1, ccp(0.4f,0.5f), CCPointZero);
     voidNode->addChild(BackgroundLayer1, 1, ccp(2.2f,1.0f), ccp(0,-200) );
     voidNode->addChild(ForegroundLayer, 2, ccp(3.0f,2.5f), ccp(200,800) );

voidNode->runAction(temp); //some action temp

    addChild(voidNode);
```

It gives  assertion failed: child->m_pParent==0
Same code works if we use sprites instead of TMXLayers.
what I have done wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers are already child nodes of the CCTMXTiledMap. A node can only have one parent.

You can try removing each layer from its parent first, the add them to voidnode. However chances are this won't work because the layers may depend on their tilemap parent.

Comment: great answer.  this really worked. Thanks for your help. There is lot less information given on internet that's why your answer is very useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
backgroundLayer->retain();
backgroundLayer->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false);
parallaxNode->addChild(backroundLayer, 0, Vec2(0, 0), Vec2(0, 0));//some points
backgroundLayer->release();
```